# Ruby string comparison and character encoding in irb

Tags: ruby

Here is the error:

```
=> ["Mænd med navnet Kim", "30.094", "29.946", "-148", "Kvinder med navnet Kim",
 "341", "345", "4", "Mænd med navnet Kim Hansen", "1.586", "1.573", "-13", "Kvin
der med navnet Kim Hansen", "5", "5", "0", "Mænd og kvinder med efternavnet Hans
en", "226.040", "223.478", "-2.562"]
irb(main):094:0>
irb(main):095:0* @tester.index("Mænd med navnet Kim")
=> nil
irb(main):096:0> @tester.index("Kvinder med navnet Kim")
=> 4
irb(main):097:0> @tester.index("Mænd med navnet Kim Hansen")
=> nil
irb(main):098:0> @tester.index("Kvinder med navnet Kim Hansen")
=> 12
irb(main):099:0> @tester.index("Mænd og kvinder med efternavnet Hansen")
=> nil
irb(main):100:0>
```

Example tried Gsub method:

```
<ap(&:text).map{|d| d.delete "'"}.map{|d| d.gsub("æ", "#844"}
irb(main):113:1> )
SyntaxError: (irb):112: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'
```

Comment: What Ruby version? I can't replicate this on 1.9.3-p194.

Comment: Among other things, as entered it appears your strings `"Kvin
der med navnet Kim Hansen"` & `"Mænd og kvinder med efternavnet Hans
en"` have newlines in them, and your fourth `index` call has a `'` in it that's not in the string in the array. Also, I assume the array shown is actually in `@tester`? You don't show the assignment call itself, only the REPL's output.

Comment: Works correctly on 1.9.2 also..hmm..

Comment: Seems to have something with encoding the æ is giving trouble...

Comment: I think we need to see the `@tester` assignment. The encodings of the string in the array might be different than the strings you type or paste into irb (just a wild guess).

Comment: Example: `@tester[0].encoding` vs typed in `"Mænd".encoding`.

Comment: "irb(main):115:0> @tester[0].encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):116:0> "Mænd".encoding
=> #<Encoding:CP850>
irb(main):117:0>"

Comment: What is the solution, I have tried the gsub method, and it gives an encoding error which I have posted.

Comment: Your gsub is missing a closing bracket - map{|d| d.gsub("æ", "#844"} should be map{|d| d.gsub("æ", "#844")}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your input strings seem to be UTF-8, the easiest solution is to run your `irb` session with the same encoding:

```
irb -EUTF-8
```

That should make string entry in the `irb` command prompt default to UTF-8.

Good resource on Ruby 1.9 encodings:
http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/understanding_m17n

Comment: You could also ensure that your `$LANG` environmental variable is set to some UTF-8 language (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`), as I believe IRB will use whatever that is set to.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes...agree. Best to unify encodings across the system. Thx.