# how to ensure irb accepts emoji input instead of escaping it?

Tags: ruby, emoji

I have two macs, from one I can merrily type all the emoji I please into `irb`, `pry`, and so forth and deal with them just like any other string.

From a newer Mac that may have a few less custom encoding configurations, I cannot do this, and I'm unsure as to why.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

Here's an animated GIF of the issue:

[image: irb escaping emoji as unicode bytes]

And here's an animated GIF of irb working normally:

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I'm not an expert in Ruby's encoding settings (UTF, etc).

Comment: Do you have a gif of the one that works? I am very n00b, but is the string closing?

Comment: sure, added a second gif

Comment: Which terminal or program are you using that creates the emoji popup?

Comment: It's an OS X system-wide keyboard palete. It can be brought up anywhere in the operating system by pressing cmd-ctrl-space.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome looked interesting. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958304/ruby-string-comparison-and-character-encoding-in-irb . What does 's.encoding' reveal? anything useful? Maybe this:  Encoding.default_external ?

Comment: Jeff: that apple question doesn't seem relevant. Chrome's rendering engine has never supported emoji.

Comment: Jeff: both strings are encoded "UTF-8", as is `Encoding.default_external`

Comment: Do the emoji's work outside irb, in the shell for example?

Comment: Casper: yes, emoji works fine in both systems in the shell

Comment: What happens if you do in shell `cat > emoji`, then type an emoji, hit enter + ctrl-d, then start irb, then `puts File.read('emoji')`?

Comment: ruby can read emoji from files fine.

Comment: I think this could lead you to a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385944/cant-enter-umlauts-in-ruby-1-9-3-irb

Comment: I.e. it could be a problem with the `readline` library compiled into your version of Ruby.

Comment: Also this one: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/185

Comment: One more: https://coderwall.com/p/wdm-_q/enable-unicode-support-in-irb

Comment: yep casper you got it. submit an answer and i'll accept it. (this worked: `brew update; brew uninstall readline; brew install readline; rbenv install`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Ruby is compiled with GNU Readline. When rvm compiles Ruby it automatically checks if Readline is installed, and if it is it will be included automatically.

You can check your Readline version in `irb`. Example:

```
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux]
irb(main):001:0> Readline::VERSION
=> "6.3"
```

So, copying your solution for installing the latest Readline with Homebrew, and then recompiling Ruby:

```
brew update; brew uninstall readline; brew install readline; rbenv install
```